# use modelstate empty validation error with <input type="button">

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I have a form in mvc razor that has two textbox and a button for saving email.
when i use submit button with onclick event, in browser, by clicking on it, it checks if email textbox is empty , shows validation error in my mvc model to fill it, but when i fill textbox and click on send button, it doesnt go to my SaveEmailForNewsletter() function and just refresh page.

```
       <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="send" onclick="javascript:SaveEmailForNewsletter();" class="ButtonStyle"/>

$("#myform").submit(
    function SaveEmailForNewsletter(e) {
    e.PreventDefault();
        var newsLetter = { Email: $("#Email").val(),Name:$("#Name").val(), LanguageId: "1" };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Newsletter/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(newsLetter),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    // We have a JSON object in case of success
                    alert('register successfuly!');
                    $('#Email').val("");
                    $("#Name").val("");
                } else {
                    // We have the partial with errors in case of failure
                    // so all we have to do is update the DOM
                    alert('This email registered previosly.');
                    $("#Email").val("");
                    $("#Name").val("");    
                 }
               }
             });
            });
```

i changed onclick to:

```
OnClick="return SaveEmailForNewsletter();"
```

it doesn't work. in both way, shows this error:

> 'javascript is not defined' or 'return SaveEmailForNewsletter() is not
>   define'

when i use input with "type=button" and onclick event, in browser, by clicking on "send button" it doesnt check for empty textbox and doesnt show any error. when i see console of firebug, it just post without anything.

```
  <input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="send" 
       onclick="SaveEmailForNewsletter();" class="ButtonStyle"/>


    function SaveEmailForNewsletter() {    
    //Code above
       });
```

I want to check textbox and if they are empty, shows modelstate validation errors, then goes to my function, excute and shows alerts.
what should i do?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem of refreshing is to do with your `<form>`. You're using a `<form>` and submitting it and then overriding the actual submit, except I don't think you are doing so currently. The better option would be to go with a regular button.

Also try to keep the wiring up of events in your JavaScript file, your markup will be a lot cleaner without it.

See example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KExz2/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitBtn').click(saveEmailForNewsletter);
});

function saveEmailForNewsletter() {
    alert('I\'m here!');
}
```

EDIT2:

Trying pulling your function out of the $("#myform").submit() function so it is in the 'global namespace'.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbBMe/1/)

```
$("#submitBtn").click(SaveEmailForNewsletter);

function SaveEmailForNewsletter(e) {

    // Use lowercase on preventDefault()
    e.preventDefault();

    var newsLetter = {
        Email: $("#Email").val(),
        Name: $("#Name").val(),
        LanguageId: "1"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Newsletter/Index',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(newsLetter),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                // We have a JSON object in case of success
                alert('register successfuly!');
                $('#Email').val("");
                $("#Name").val("");
            } else {
                // We have the partial with errors in case of failure
                // so all we have to do is update the DOM
                alert('This email registered previosly.');
                $("#Email").val("");
                $("#Name").val("");
            }
        }
    });

    // Will stop the submit
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me, when i use "type=button", it doesn't show and save anything. when i use "type=submit", it shows modelstate validation error next to my textbox, but it doesn't save anything  and doesn't show alert.

Comment: Added how to prevent submit, try this too.

Comment: Thanks, but i get this error: "ReferenceError: saveEmailForNewsletter is not defined
[Break On This Error]  
$('#submitBtn').click(saveEmailForNewsletter);"

Comment: Ah, I think your problem may be that your function is inside your submit function so it can't be seen when you're hooking it up.

Comment: my function is in this js file: '<script src="../../Scripts/Services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' and i use '<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submitBtn').click(saveEmailForNewsletter);
    });
</script>' before or after it. i also put your code insied my service.js file. but i get this error yet:"ReferenceError: saveEmailForNewsletter is not defined"

Comment: Hmm... Could you throw the current state of everything into a JSFiddle? Ideally getting the same error message as you get, you can just comment out things like the AJAX call to get a complete working example. Getting a little confusing now :P